# I am getting output from a different array when using random()

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding so I'm having trouble with this.

I am trying to create a game where you get a random cuisine and from that cuisine you get a random restaurant for that particular cuisine.

However, when I run the code, I end up getting a restaurant for a different cuisine sometimes.

```js
let whereToEat = prompt("Shall we go out to eat today");
let choice;
let cuisines = ["Italian", "Korean", "Thai", "Mediterranean", "Turkish"];
let italianRestaurant = ["Vapiano", "Bella Italia", "Grato"];
let koreanRestaurant = ["Superstar bbq", "Bari Bari", "Korean bbq and vegan"];
let thaiRestaurant = ["Thai pot", "Wok n Roll", "Farang"];
let mediterraneanRestaurant = ["Mediterrnean cafe and restaurant", "Seabird", "Nopi"];
let turkishRestaurant = ["Gokyuzu", "Antalya restaurant", "La'De kitchen"];


function whatToEat(choices) {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  return choices[index];
};

if (whereToEat === "yes") {
  alert("Great");
  alert("Lets try " + whatToEat(cuisines));
  if (whatToEat(cuisines) === "Italian") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(italianRestaurant));
  } else if (whatToEat(cuisines) === "Korean") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(koreanRestaurant));
  } else if (whatToEat(cuisines) === "Thai") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(thaiRestaurant));
  } else if (whatToEat(cuisines) === "Mediterranean") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(mediterraneanRestaurant));
  } else if (whatToEat(cuisines) === "Turkish") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(turkishRestaurant));
  }
} else {
  alert("Ahh I was hoping you would say yes");
}
```

Comment: When possible, try to move past `prompt()` and `alert()` for user interactivity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling your random whatToEat function twice on the 'cuisines' array, which will give you two different results.
Store the result in a binding so it doesn't change:

```
const choice = whatToEat(cuisines);
alert("Lets try " + choice);
if (choice === "Italian") { ... etc
```

Comment: Ah! Missed it by 30 seconds while I was typing ;)

Comment: I'd like to add: it would be much cooler to store these arrays in a `map`, that way you don't have to recode your entire program every time a different regional cuisine is added.

Answer (score 3):

Store the result of `whatToEat` so your calling it once not in each if statement.

```js
let whereToEat = prompt("Shall we go out to eat today");
let cuisines = ["Italian", "Korean", "Thai", "Mediterranean", "Turkish"];
let italianRestaurant = ["Vapiano", "Bella Italia", "Grato"];
let koreanRestaurant = ["Superstar bbq", "Bari Bari", "Korean bbq and vegan"];
let thaiRestaurant = ["Thai pot", "Wok n Roll", "Farang"];
let mediterraneanRestaurant = ["Mediterrnean cafe and restaurant", "Seabird", "Nopi"];
let turkishRestaurant = ["Gokyuzu", "Antalya restaurant", "La'De kitchen"];


function whatToEat(choices) {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  return choices[index];
};

if (whereToEat === "yes") {
  const choice = whatToEat(cuisines);
  alert("Great");
  alert("Lets try " + choice);
  if (choice === "Italian") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(italianRestaurant));
  } else if (choice === "Korean") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(koreanRestaurant));
  } else if (choice === "Thai") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(thaiRestaurant));
  } else if (choice === "Mediterranean") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(mediterraneanRestaurant));
  } else if (choice === "Turkish") {
    alert("Let's go here: " + whatToEat(turkishRestaurant));
  }
} else {
  alert("Ahh I was hoping you would say yes");
}
```